# how to add files with same name in different folders of xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to have two files with the same name in different folders in a xcode project. These files are actually code files and not any resource files. How can I achieve this?

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: If possible : It would cost you more (would conflict header file names and more ),anyway why do you want So ?

Comment: @jhaliya I want to integrate twitter and myspace in my applications. There are libraries available for both of them but few of the files are having same names.

Comment: I don't know,but I'm sure there must be some way to handle the conflict (it's common that two 3rd party library would have same name of files) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if there .h/.m files you can't have them in the same project, even if they are in different directories.
C does not support namespaces, so every class has to have an unique name.

Comment: actually these files are from some library for twitter and myspace integration. There is a conflict because of same name in some of the files. is there a way out?

Comment: @pankaj: just build the library separately, e.g. from the command line, and then add the compiled library to your Xcode project

Comment: @Paul R. Nope this will not work. Eq if both lib use the OauthLib than there will be a conflict. I've no idea on how to slove this.

Comment: can you please point me to some tutorial for this as I have no idea regarding how to do this

Answer (score -1):

You can add, but when you load it, the system will pick the first one available. 
So, really it will not work the way you expect.